# change all columns based on the maximum value in each row

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large data frame which has multiple columns calculated from other columns. The issues come where there are values of 8888 and 9999 which constitute NA or refused to answer respectively. These values have been incorrectly used to calculate other columns (such as the value of `pricepergram`) as they have not been signaled as NA prior to calculation.

I'm not able to recalculate all the values, so instead I would like to find some code, which takes in as an argument each row of the dataframe. If the maximum value in the row is above 8887, then I would like it to return the row but with the value of all prices set to NA.

- the solution needs to be applicable to a dataframe of 250 columns.
- I need to be able to apply the code across multiple columns, rather than just one.
- I have confirmed that the only values above 8887 in the dataframe are indeed either 9999 or 8888 and therefore constitute values that we want to change.

I am not able to post the dataset due to data protection (apologies), but have given an example of minimum complexity to illustrate my point.

[image]

This would be the ideal output:

[image]

The rows with values above 8887 have had their price set to NA.

Comment: @Maël hi, have added in as an edit!

Comment: Can you also share your dataframe? use dput. Otherwise it's not possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Maël sorry- I can't. Data protection means that there's details in there that I cant share.

Answer (score 1):

We can break this problem into two steps:

1. find out if there are any 8888 or 9999 codes in a row
2. set values in the row to NA

**Step 1:** The following code produces an indicator for whether a row contains any codes greater than 8887:

```r
any_large_codes = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(row){any(row > 8887)})
```

It works as follows: `apply` treats the dataframe as a matrix. `MARGIN = 1` means that the function is applied to each row of the matrix. `function(row){any(row > 8887)}` checks if any value in its input (each row) is larger than 8887.

I have not used dplyr for this as I am not aware of any row-wise operators in dplyr. This seems the best option. You can use dplyr to add it into the dataframe if you wish, but this is not necessary:

```r
df = df %>% mutate(na_indicator = any_large_codes)
```

**Step 2:** The following code sets the values in a single column to NA where there are any large codes:

```r
df = df %>%
  mutate(this_one_column = ifelse(any_large_codes, NA, this_one_column))
```

If you want to handle multiple columns, I would suggest something like this:

```r
all_columns_to_handle = c(
  "col1",
  "col2",
  "col3",
  ...
)

for(cc in all_columns_to_handle){
  df = df %>%
    mutate(!!sym(cc) := ifelse(any_large_codes, NA, !!sym(cc)))
}
```

Where `!!sym(cc)` is a way to use the column name stored in `cc` and `:=` is equivalent to `=` but allows us to use `!!sym(cc)` on the left-hand side. For other options to this approach see the programming with dplyr vignette.